# Machine Learning nominal data

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Im working on machine learning with svm. I try to feed my svm with data, but my data is nominal and i have no idea how to transform it.

My data looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Item | Productname | Label name | Packaging |etc...
--------------------------------------------------
1 | Battery Micro 4 | Batt. Micro | Folding|...
--------------------------------------------------
2 | Battery Micro 8 | Batt. Micro | Blister|...
--------------------------------------------------
3 | button cell Battery | btn Batt. | Blister | ...
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to train my svm to identify that "Battery Micro 4" is column "Productname"
and "Batt. Micro" is column "label name" and Folding is column "Packaging" so on.

Methods like onehot seems not to be good for my case.
The number of items will increase after some time.

Does anyone know a method to transform these data to numerical values with less information loss?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data has no natural ordering it would be of no use to use integer encoding. Next option would have been one hot encoding but as you said the no of items can increase we can discard this as well, next option is to get a value count of all the discrete values you have sort them and then do an integer encoding going from smallest to largest, while doing this step you should also take care about the cardinality of discrete values, if you have an discrete element with a cardinality <1% it would be better to create a special category for these values and add all such value to that category, this way any new category that arrives during test time should be assign to this category as its cardinality would definitely be very low.